# Gitlab CI stage didn't get variables if add needs

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration

file content like following:

```yaml
first:
  stage: init
  script:
    - echo "AA=2" >> vars.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: vars.env

.build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - |
      echo ${AA} # got 2

run:
  stage: build
  needs:
    - build-image
  script:
    - |
      echo ${AA} # got empty
      

build-image:
  extends: .build
  variables:
    VARS_2: test
```

If I add `needs` in `run` stage, {AA} will print empty.
If I remove `needs` section in `run` stage, {AA} will print 2.

How to solve it?